# I don't know how to get slash commands working for my dice command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a dice slash command with a command handler that posts a picture of the dice, but it says `url1` `undefined`. When I try just posting the pictures directly, it says *interaction failed: this interaction has already been acknowledged*.

```js
module.exports= {
    name: "diceslash",
    description:"dice slashcommand",
    execute(interaction){
        const diceroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
        const dices = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

        const ans = diceroll + dices;

        if (diceroll == 1){
            const url1 = 'https://imgur.com/a/YdAmiRe';
        }
        if (diceroll == 2){
            const url1 = 'https://imgur.com/a/w35gKMR';
        }
        if (diceroll == 3){
            const url1 = 'https://imgur.com/a/MkDVhQS';
        }
        if (diceroll == 4){  
            const url1 = 'https://imgur.com/a/WCuaCbL';         
        }
        if (diceroll == 5){
            const url1 = 'https://imgur.com/a/0xyPIkx';
        }
        if (diceroll == 6){
            const url1 = 'https://imgur.com/a/urv1H42';
        }
        if (dices == 1){
            const url2 = 'https://imgur.com/a/YdAmiRe';
        }
        if (dices == 2){
            const url2 = 'https://imgur.com/a/w35gKMR';
        }
        if (dices == 3){
            const url2 = 'https://imgur.com/a/MkDVhQS';
        }
        if (dices == 4){  
            const url2 = 'https://imgur.com/a/WCuaCbL';         
        }
        if (dices == 5){
            const url2 = 'https://imgur.com/a/0xyPIkx';
        }
        if (dices == 6){
            const url2 = 'https://imgur.com/a/urv1H42';
        }
     
        interaction.reply ({content: url1+" "+url2})
        interaction.reply({content: "you got "+ ans})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` is block scoped, so `url1` and `url2` are only available inside the if statements. Outside of those blocks, these variables are `undefined`.

You probably shouldn't use so many if statements though. Just store the images in an array or a map and pick one of those like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'diceslash',
  description: 'dice slashcommand',
  execute(interaction) {
    const dices = [
      'https://imgur.com/a/YdAmiRe',
      'https://imgur.com/a/w35gKMR',
      'https://imgur.com/a/MkDVhQS',
      'https://imgur.com/a/WCuaCbL',
      'https://imgur.com/a/0xyPIkx',
      'https://imgur.com/a/urv1H42',
    ];
    const dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    const dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    const ans = dice1 + dice2;
    // array's index starts at zero
    const url1 = dices[dice1 - 1];
    const url2 = dices[dice2 - 1];

    interaction.reply({ content: `${url1} ${url2} \n you got ${ans}` });
  },
};
```

You could also store the dices in an object with their URLs and values and simplify it like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'diceslash',
  description: 'dice slashcommand',
  execute(interaction) {
    const dices = [
      { url: 'https://imgur.com/a/YdAmiRe', value: 1 },
      { url: 'https://imgur.com/a/w35gKMR', value: 2 },
      { url: 'https://imgur.com/a/MkDVhQS', value: 3 },
      { url: 'https://imgur.com/a/WCuaCbL', value: 4 },
      { url: 'https://imgur.com/a/0xyPIkx', value: 5 },
      { url: 'https://imgur.com/a/urv1H42', value: 6 },
    ];
    // helper function to pick a random item from an array
    const pick = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    const dice1 = pick(dices);
    const dice2 = pick(dices);
    const ans = dice1.value + dice2.value;

    interaction.reply({ content: `${dice1.url} ${dice2.url}` });
    interaction.followUp({ content: `you got ${ans}` });
  },
};
```

As for the second part of your question; the error is thrown because you try to reply to an interaction twice. An interaction can only be responded to once. You could either send a single response (see my first snippet) or use the [`followUp()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=followUp) method for the second message (see the second snippet).